# Strange Message on Wordpress

Tags: php, css, wordpress

```html
<!--functions.php-->
<?php

function learningWordPress_resources() {

 wp_enqueue_style('style', get_stylesheet_uri());

}

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'learningWordPress_resources');
```

I get the message "class="home blog logged-in admin-bar no-customize-support">" below my navigation bar in the wordpress I am coding from scratch. Does anyone know how to remove this? If so, your help would be much appreciated : )

(The attached code won't run here because it's dependent on wordpress. Hopefully, the attached picture is enough to explain the situation)

```css
/* 
CSS:
Theme Name: Yonsei Fencing
Author: Yonsei Student
Version: 1.0
*/
```

```html
<!--index.php-->
<?php

get_header();

if (have_posts()) : 
 while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

 <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
 <?php the_content(); ?>
 
 <?php endwhile;

 else: 
  echo '<p>No content found</p>';

 endif;

get_footer();

?>

<!--header.php-->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html> <?php language_attributes(); ?>>
 <head>
  <meta charset="<?php bloginfo('charset'); ?>">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title><?php bloginfo('name'); ?></title>
  <?php wp_head(); ?>
 </head>

<body> <?php body_class(); ?>>

 <!--site-header-->
 <header class="site-header">
  <h1><a href="<?php echo home_url(); ?>"><?php bloginfo('name'); ?></a></h1>
  <h5><?php bloginfo('description'); ?></h5>
 </header><!--/site-header-->


<!--footer.php-->
<footer class="site-footer">

 <p><?php bloginfo('name'); ?> - &copy; <?php echo date('Y');?></p>

</footer>

<?php wp_footer(); ?>
</body>
</html>
```

[image: My webpage]

Comment: Have you added any custom function in your `functions.php` file for customizing body classes?

Comment: Hi, I just added one now, but nothing seems to change.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The issue is that the function [body_class()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/body_class) belongs *inside* your `body` tag, but in the code you've posted, it's *after* the `body` tag.

Change your code as follows, and you're good to go:

FROM this, which closes the body tag first:

```
<body> <?php body_class(); ?>>
```

TO this, which contains the `body_class` inside the body tag:

```
<body <?php body_class(); ?>>
```

Comment: Thank you sir! : )